# Getting undefined variable with if exist

Tags: matlab

I assume this is a trivial mistake on my part but it is driving me nuts.

```
???Undefined function or variable "antenna_02".

Error in ==>test_model at 6
if exist(antenna_02.mat, 'file')
```

I know it isn't defined that is why I am using if exist. Any help would be gladly appreciated and may just save my sanity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enclose "antenna_02.mat" in apostrophes (`''`):

```
if exist('antenna_02.mat', 'file')
```

Otherwise MATLAB tries to interpret it as a [structure variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) and complains that there's no variable called `antenna_02`.

Comment: We have all been there! :)